# if statement help in java

Tags: java, if-statement

My program has two inputs num1 and num2. I want a condition for my if statement where both the inputs should not be zero and both the inputs should be greater than zero but less than or equal to 1000. The while loop should break with input 0 0 onl. Should i hava two if statements?

```
    while (true)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        int num2 = input.nextInt();

        if ((num1 <= 1000 && num2 <= 1000) && (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0))
        {
                 for (int num = num1; num <= num2; num++)
                        System.out.println(num);
        }
        else if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: `num>0` implies `n!=0`, so you can omit first part

Comment: if ((num1 > 0 && num1 <= 1000) && (num2 > 0 && num2 <= 1000))

Comment: its not considering those conditions

Comment: There are no [tag:parameters] here. I punctuated and capitalized this unintelligible mess for you.

Comment: How can you call this unintelligible if you have too much knowledge build your senses first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is redundant as you want that these vars be in a range out of them `(1-1000)`:

```
(num1!=0||num2!=0)
```

Just specify the expected range :

```
if (num1 > 0 && num1 <= 1000 && num2 > 0 && num2 <= 1000) {
   ...
}
```

> the while loop should break with input 0 0 only should i hava two if statements?

Not necessary. The actual problem is that `Scanner.nextInput()` is not used in your `while`. 
So it will never work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like that:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    int num1 = input.nextInt();
    int num2 = input.nextInt();
    if (num1|num2 == 0) break;

    if (num1<=1000 && num2<=1000 && (num1|num2)>0)
        // do your action
}
```

Note single `|` between variable to perform binary OR instead of logical one

Comment: should i use if and else if

Comment: @Unknownuser its up to you, both will work the same in this case